# Passing String variable between two main classes, passing it into String Array

Tags: java, arrays, excel, apache-poi

I am working on java IBAN Validator that should take IBAN numbers from particular Excel column and validate them with output "valid/invalid".

I have the validator itself set up in IBANChecker03.java class. It works just fine when I put any number of IBAN numbers into `String[] ibans = {"iban number placed here"}`

In my second class, temporarily called "HomeOffice.java", I have all the handeling of the Excel file. It iterates through the raws and takes all the IBANs for me + stores it into "cellvalue" variable.

Now I need to kind of connect these two classes together, which is what I am currently stuck on.

May you please help me how can I now take results from `cellvalue` and pass it into IBANChecker03.java class in `String[] ibans = {""}` so that it validates the ibans for me?

What would be the best thing of doing this?

Here is the code:

```
public class IBANChecker03
{
    private static final String DEFSTRS = ""
        + "AL28 AD24 AT20 AZ28 BE16 BH22 BA20 BR29 BG22 "
        + "HR21 CY28 CZ24 DK18 DO28 EE20 FO18 FI18 FR27 GE22 DE22 GI23 "
        + "GL18 GT28 HU28 IS26 IE22 IL23 IT27 KZ20 KW30 LV21 LB28 LI21 "
        + "LT20 LU20 MK19 MT31 MR27 MU30 MC27 MD24 ME22 NL18 NO15 PK24 "
        + "PS29 PL28 PT25 RO24 SM27 SA24 RS22 SK24 SI19 ES24 SE24 CH21 "
        + "TN24 TR26 AE23 GB22 VG24 GR27 CR21";
    private static final Map<String, Integer> DEFINITIONS = new HashMap<>();

    static
    {
        for (String definition : DEFSTRS.split(" "))
            DEFINITIONS.put(definition.substring(0, 2), Integer.parseInt(definition.substring(2)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception
    {
        String[] ibans = {"IBAN goes here"};

        // HERE I NEED TO PASS Cell Values from HomeOffice.java

        for (String iban : ibans)
            System.out.printf("%s is %s.%n", iban, validateIBAN(iban) ? "valid" : "not valid");
    }

    static boolean validateIBAN(String iban)
    {
        iban = iban.replaceAll("\\s", "").toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);

        int len = iban.length();
        if (len < 4 || !iban.matches("[0-9A-Z]+") || DEFINITIONS.getOrDefault(iban.substring(0, 2), 0) != len)
            return false;

        iban = iban.substring(4) + iban.substring(0, 4);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            sb.append(Character.digit(iban.charAt(i), 36));

        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(sb.toString());
        return bigInt.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(97)).intValue() == 1;
    }
}

public class HomeOffice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        File excelFile = new File("IBNTEST.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Here we start iterating through raws and cells
        Iterator<Row> rowIt=sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIt.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 7) { // Choose number of column 
                    System.out.println(cell.toString() + ","); // Print cells
                    String cellvalue = cell.toString();   // This I need to pass into IBANCHECKER03.java
                    // Pass into  String[] ibans = {};

                    //-----------HERE I NEED TO CONNECT TO IBANChecker
                }
                workbook.close();
                fis.close();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Question questions ;)
Are you using an IDE, and are both of these Java files in your IDE project?

Comment: Yes, of course. :) I am running this in NetBeans and both java files are in one project under the same package. It is just a matter of connecting these together so that I can finalize the project.

Comment: Do you need them to both have a `main` method? `IBANChecker03` seems like it's just a utility class. Are you wanting `IBANChecker03` to print the results when called from `HomeOffice`? If so, I think you can just call `IBANChecker03.main(ibans)` from `HomeOffice`. But it's weird to call `main`, so maybe just move the logic into a different function and call it from `main` in `IBANChecker03` and from `HomeOffice`.

Comment: Hi Makaque, thank you for your response! May you please be more specific? I am trying to call IBANChecker03.main(ibans) but I am probably missing the logic, nothing works for me. Could you maybe provide some code so that I have something to start with? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `args` passed to `IBANChecker03.main` as the array of strings to check, you can easily call it with an array of strings from `HomeOffice` like so:

```
public class IBANChecker03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ibans = args;
        for(String iban : ibans){
            System.out.printf("%s is %s.%n", iban, validateIBAN(iban) ? "valid" : "not valid");
        }
    }

    static boolean validateIBAN(String iban){
        // validation code
    }
}

public class HomeOffice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] vals = new String[]{"5616516", "8984546", "6516546", "9684654"};
        IBANChecker03.main(vals);
    }
}
```

However, in the code you've provided, You're iterating through each cell, and you've indicated that you wish to pass the individual cell value to `IBANChecker03`. This value:

```
String cellvalue = cell.toString();
```

You can handle this in a number of ways. You could package the cell value into an array and pass it:

```
String[] cellvalue = new String[]{cell.toString()};
IBANChecker03.main(cellValue);
```

You can make `validateIBAN` public, or if these to classes are in the same package then you can just call it directly since methods are package private by default:

```
String cellvalue = cell.toString();
if(IBANChecker03.validateIBAN(cellvalue)){
    //Do Something
}
```

If what you're really interested in is having `IBANChecker03` validate and print for a single cell, but you want the `main` method there for testing or whatever else, then just move that logic out of `main` like so:

```
public class IBANChecker03 {

    public static void printValid(String iban){
        System.out.printf("%s is %s.%n", iban, validateIBAN(iban) ? "valid" : "not valid");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ibans = {"IBAN goes here"};
        for(String iban : ibans){
            printValid(iban);
        }
    }

    static boolean validateIBAN(String iban){
        //Validation code
    }
}

public class HomeOffice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Code to get cell
        String cellvalue = cell.toString();
        IBANChecker03.printValid(cellvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Makaque, thank you very much! I think it is almost there, not yet though. Now I think I lost the excel cells iterator to do the job, it is not even printing the iterated cells now. When I run the code it still prints only the value of  String[] ibans = {"IBAN goes here"};. I need this array to take the scanned IBAN numbers stored in cellvalue variable in HomeOffice.java and show if IBANs are valid/invalid.

Comment: false alarm, ti started working with a bit of tweaking, thank you very much! Finally I can proceed with this further. :)